# iOS Instantiate Custom View from Nib File across multiple UIViewController

Tags: ios, xib, custom-view

I need an example of how to instantiate a custom view from a nib file. i wrapped my head around several stackoverflow posts but i didn't get it. Maybe i only need a hint how to do it.

what I want to do is - creating a custom view with interface builder. it should be a template so that i can instantiate it multiple times to add it to multiple view controllers.

So far I have created my custom view xib file called MyIssueView.xib. Which consists in fact just of the main view and some labels.

And I created a Subclass of UIView which is called IssueView with the Outlets for my labels in the MyIssueView.xib.

How do I now hook up the outlets with the IB? And how can I instantiate the IssueView from any ViewController?

Would be glad for an example!
Cheers.

**UPDATE:**

I now have

IssueView.xib
IssueView.h (UIView Subclass)
IssueView.m

My IssueView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IssueView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label4;

@end
```

My IssueView.m:

```
#import "IssueView.h"

@implementation IssueView
@end
```

My ViewController.m:

```
#import "AllIssuesViewController1.h"
#import "IssueView.h"
#import "UIView+NibLoading.h"

@interface AllIssuesViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation AllIssuesViewController1


- (void) loadView
{

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _issueView = [IssueView loadInstanceFromNib];
}
```

It gives me an error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x8292580> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label1.'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a category that extends UIView called UIView+NibLoading.

In it is this code...

```
#import "UIView+NibLoading.h"

@implementation UIView (NibLoading)

+ (id)loadInstanceFromNib
{
    UIView *result;

    NSArray* elements = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id anObject in elements) {
        if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
            result = anObject;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

@end
```

Then when I want to instantiate a UIView subclass from a nib I just import the category and I can run...

```
self.issueView = [IssueView loadInstanceFromNib];\
```

You need to connect the labels like this...

[image]

If you connecting the labels to "File's Owner" then you'll need to remove those connections.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I assume I have to set my IssueView as class of the MainView in the file inspector in the interface builder? and hook up the outlets?

Comment: Yes, set the main view of the IB file to the IssueView. (note, leave the "file's owner" as just NSObject. And you have to call the files the same thing.  blah.h and blah.m and blah.xib

Comment: i get an error look at my update. it happens in the category - on the line where it says NSArray *elements = ...

Comment: Looks like a problem with the label1 property that you have. Also, I don't know why but whenever I use it in viewDidLoad I always cast it to the type.  issueView = (IssueView*)[IssueView loadInstanceFromNib];

Comment: Oh, you are connecting the labels to the wrong place. It looks like you are connecting the label outlets to the "file's owner". You need to connect them to the view. Leave the file's owner completely alone, nothing should be done with it.

Comment: Yes connect them to the IssueView.  But the IssueView is NOT the "File's Owner". The IssueView is the first UIView that you lay down in InterfaceBuilder. I'll see if I can attach an image to help.

Comment: Ok got it. But there is another strange error. When I want to add the IssueView as a Subview to my ViewController I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Make sure your issueView property is strong. Then you can just add it by saying [self.view addSubView:self.issueView];

Comment: ah ok my fault ;). I added method loadView without calling super! Thanks for your support fogmeister!!!! works like a charm now!

Comment: This piece of category looks awesome! Is it reliable? across ios'es etc?